# How to Get the Values of $emit Payload in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, events

I'm new to vuejs and had to use date range picker. I'm using `vue-rangedate-picker` and after selecting a date range, $emit type event is fired and I found the required values in the payload of the event as shown below (event info taken from vue debugger):

```
name: "selected"
type: "$emit"
source: "<vue-rangedate-picker>"
payload: Array[1]
  0: Object
    end: "Fri May 31 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
    start: "Wed May 01 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

I need to get the values in payload so I can assign to variables and use them later. I tried to find the solution for hours and had no luck.
Here is the element

```
<vue-rangedate-picker
  righttoleft="true"
  i18n="EN"
  format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
  @selected="testDatePicker()"
></vue-rangedate-picker>
```

And the script

```
testDatePicker() {
  console.log(/*what should I write here to get the payload?*/);
}
```

How do I get the payload values so I can assign them to variables? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function testDatePicker will receive the range in the following form:

```
testDatePicker({start, end}) {
  console.log(start, end);
}
```

or if you prefer:

```
testDatePicker(range) {
  console.log(range.start, range.end);
}
```

Also, you should not use parenthesis in the call:

```
<vue-rangedate-picker
  righttoleft="true"
  i18n="EN"
  format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
  @selected="testDatePicker"
></vue-rangedate-picker>
```

Like that, you pass a "reference" to your method, and the component will call it with needed parameters.